# $X$ and $Y$ are independent of $Z$, Will any linear combination of X and Y be independent of Z?

Tags: random-variables

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent of Z, will any combination of $X$ and $Y$ be independent of Z?

$aX+bY \perp Z$?

Will that independence holds if $X \perp Y$?

Comment: What happens when you try to prove it?

Comment: One approach: think of $\sigma$-algebras and note that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f(W)$ where $W=(X,Y)$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $W$. This should allow you to show that $f(W)$ and $Z$ are independent whenever $W$ and $Z$ are. This is true for any measurable $f$, including $f(X,Y)=aX+bY$.

Comment: @KimJongUn Unfortunately, the approach you outline is wrong: one can have (X,Y) independent, (X,Z) independent, (Y,Z) independent, and *yet*, (X,Y,Z) *not* independent. Exercise: Provide an example.

Comment: @Vincent: No. Try (X,Y,Z) uniformly distributed on {(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,1)}.

Comment: @Did I haven't thought about your example but I still think what I said is suitable to the problem of the OP.

Comment: @KimJongUn Where do you see in "the problem of the OP" the hypothesis that (X,Y) is independent of Z?

Comment: The very first phrase, that's how I read it.

Comment: @KimJongUn Please read better, it nowhere says that (X,Y) is independent of Z, only that X is independent of Z and that Y is independent of Z. You would not think that this implies that (X,Y) is independent of Z, by any chance, would you? (Unrelated: Please use @.)